# hosts file seems to be ignored

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, hosts

I have almost fresh Ubuntu desktop box. OS was installed two weeks ago and updated from karmic repositories. Last week I had no problems with DNS. But this week something had changed. I'm not sure what and when, and not sure whether I changed any configs.

So now I have some really weird situation. According to logs name resolving should work normally.

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost test
127.0.1.1   desktop
```

**/etc/host.conf**

```
order hosts,bind
multi on
```

**/etc/resolv.conf**

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search search servers obtained via DHCP
nameserver 192.168.0.3
```

**/etc/nsswitch.conf**

```
passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

But if fact it is not.

**user@test ~>ping test**

```
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
[skip]
```

Pinging is ok.

**user@test ~>host test**

```
test.mydomain.com has address xx.xxx.161.201
```

I suspect that NetworkManager might cause this misbehavior, but don't know where to start to check it.
Any thoughts, suggestions?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With this configuration, most applications will happily work with your entry from `/etc/hosts`.

However `host` doesn't look at `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.  That is by design, not by accident, since `host` is *specifically* a DNS lookup program.  `/etc/hosts` is not DNS, it's (mostly) what we used *before* we had DNS.

The same is also true for `dig` and `nslookup` - they're DNS specific too.

Comment: So, you're saying, `host` utility doesn't use `/etc/hosts`? And there's nothing to fix in my case?

Comment: yup, pretty much - nothing to see here :)

Comment: What I don't get is that `host` >used to< be the "regular" name-querying command, obeying `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

Comment: @Kwaio I can find no evidence in the ISC sources that `host` ever did

Comment: Well I might have used unsual distribution implementations, then, my bad.

Answer (score 21):

The `host` command (along with `dig` and `nslookup`) is part of the `bind` DNS utilities. As a DNS resolver utility, it does DNS resolution alone.

If you're interested in fetching an entry from any `libnss`-driven data store, you can use the `getent` program. To get a hosts entry, for example, use it like this:

```
getent hosts google.com
```

This follows the resolution order set out under `hosts:` in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` in order, which includes `/etc/hosts` if "files" is lised as one of the options.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me the `getent` command.

Comment: I believe that nowadays one should be using `getent ahosts` instead of `getent hosts` because `getent hosts` uses `gethostbyaddr()` or `gethostbyname*()` which are obsolete. If I have understood correctly, `getent hosts` emulates how old UNIX C programs used to work and `getent ahosts` emulates the way moderm programs should work.

Answer (score 2):

For me this issue occurred due to incorrect file permissions. Only root could read /etc/hosts. The file should be world-readable.

Answer (score 1):

These days (2021) Firefox is using DNS over HTTPS which you have to disable for it to respect your hosts file. I think this has some privacy implications, so get informed before you do it.

Go to Firefox settings, search DNS. Click `settings` next to `Configure how firefox connects to the internet`. At the bottom, uncheck `Enable DNS over HTTPS`